# Getting IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed on session.evict()

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-session

I'm getting the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireEvict(SessionImpl.java:1395)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.evict(SessionImpl.java:1391)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.PGPaymentService.deleteAndSave(PGPaymentService.java:259)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.PGPaymentService.reconTransaction(PGPaymentService.java:224)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.impl.PhonePeService.reconTransaction(PhonePeService.java:88)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.impl.PhonePeService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$312adb03.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.impl.PhonePeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6a3598f.reconTransaction(<generated>)
    at com.hotstar.payment.schedulers.tasks.ReconTask.reconPendingTransactions(ReconTask.java:124)
    at com.hotstar.payment.schedulers.tasks.ReconTask$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d6e2cee2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.scheduling.TraceSchedulingAspect.traceBackgroundThread(TraceSchedulingAspect.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.hotstar.payment.schedulers.tasks.ReconTask$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10269f04.reconPendingTransactions(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-10-03 12:32:00.741 ERROR [-,76fca589eb38a4c2,76fca589eb38a4c2,false] 1 --- [taskScheduler-4] c.h.payment.service.PGPaymentService     : STACKTRACE
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireEvict(SessionImpl.java:1395)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.evict(SessionImpl.java:1391)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.PGPaymentService.deleteAndSave(PGPaymentService.java:259)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.PGPaymentService.reconTransaction(PGPaymentService.java:224)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.impl.PhonePeService.reconTransaction(PhonePeService.java:88)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.impl.PhonePeService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$312adb03.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.hotstar.payment.service.impl.PhonePeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6a3598f.reconTransaction(<generated>)
    at com.hotstar.payment.schedulers.tasks.ReconTask.reconPendingTransactions(ReconTask.java:124)
    at com.hotstar.payment.schedulers.tasks.ReconTask$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d6e2cee2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.scheduling.TraceSchedulingAspect.traceBackgroundThread(TraceSchedulingAspect.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.hotstar.payment.schedulers.tasks.ReconTask$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10269f04.reconPendingTransactions(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For the following code:

```java
try {
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    session.evict(userSubscriptions);
    UserSubscriptions deleteObject = userSubscriptionsDao.findByHidAndCommercialPack(userSubscriptions.getHid(), userSubscriptions.getCommercialPack());

    if (deleteObject != null) {
        userSubscriptionsDao.delete(deleteObject);
        userSubscriptionsDao.flush();
    }

    userSubscriptionsDao.saveAndFlush(userSubscriptions.duplicate());
    return userSubscriptions;
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Basically I'm trying to delete the entity before saving it. There may be multiple threads which would execute the same code but not able to figure out what is causing the IllegalStateException. Can someone please help me with what is wrong?

```
@Repository
public interface UserSubscriptionsDAO extends JpaRepository<UserSubscriptions, Long> {
```

Comment: if you are using `JpaRepository` why do you wanna do this explicitly?

Comment: This is required because I want to change the primary key  value in userSubscriptionsDao in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with

```
userSubscriptionsDao.saveAndFlush(userSubscriptions.duplicate());
```

You are persisting a detached entity.

Instead, **merge** the UserSubscription entity object. It will work as you expected.

Comment: I believe saveAndFlush reattaches the entity. Nonetheless I'm doing "userSubscriptions.duplicate()" which is like a copy constructor to create new object of userSubscriptions.

Comment: For your requirements, you can just find the stored object and perform edit with setters and merge the object.

Comment: This would throw an exception saying Original Identity modified.

Comment: You can specify updatable=true

Comment: Doesn't work that way either. Throws Identity modified exception. The only way is to evict + delete  entity and save it again.